# ethernet and wireless do not work on Lenovo W520 under Ubuntu 10.04.3

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, intel

An Ubuntu newbie installed CAELinux 2011 which is based on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS 64bit side-by-side with Windows 7 on Lenovo W520. Although both ethernet and wireless cards work on Windows 7, they do not on Ubuntu. The cards are Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection and Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205, respectively. Where the drivers can be found and how to install them? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu; other distributions are offtopic here, try our friends at the [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Well first step I did was take a look here at the Ubuntu Cert Site:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201103-7374

It looks like that your model was certified in 10.10 codenamed (Maverick)

I see in your description that CAElinux 2011 is based on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS (Lucid) which is the release prior Maverick

> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx)
>
> Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)
> I
> Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)
>
> Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)
>
> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)

I think it's safe to say that if your looking for an easy user experience your going to have to find a updated version thats based on 10.10 or better.

I found the following link while researching your network card. I think you should be able to follow along the thread and resolve your issue. You will probably have to download the module source on a different computer and transfer it via USB key. Hope this helps!

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1741686.html